# Factor Variable Labelling but proportionally

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am organizing data set and have a problem regarding to factor variables. I have a gender variable total count of 3246 and most of them are males. I have 50 `NA`'s in the gender category. I do not want to delete the observations with `NA`'s but also do not want to replace all of it with the 'male' or 'female'. I would like to change randomly 7 of the NA's to 'female' and 43 to 'male'. However, I could not manage it.

I already know how to change `NA`'s to one type.

```
data$Gender[is.na(data$Gender)] = 'male'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may subset the variable using `is.na()` into an `na` object, create a `sample` out of the value `u`niverse of length of the `sum` of the `TRUE`'s in `na`, and replace the subset with the new sample. Here an example:

```
## example data
n <- 1e3
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(c('f', 'm'), n, replace=TRUE)
x[sample(length(x), 50)] <- NA
table(x, useNA="ifany")
# x
#     f    m <NA> 
#   476  474   50 

## solution 1
u <- unique(na.omit(x))  ## value universe  
na <- is.na(x)  ## subset variable
x[na] <- sample(u, sum(na), replace=TRUE)  ## new sample
table(x, useNA="ifany")  ## result
# x
#   f   m 
# 504 496
```

You may also use the proportions of the non-missing data to create females and males with like so:

```
## solution 2 (Note: Create example data again from above)
p <- proportions(table(x))  ## proportions
na <- is.na(x)  ## subset variable
x[na] <- sample(names(p), sum(na), replace=TRUE, prob=p)  ## new sample
table(x, useNA="ifany")  ## result
# x
#   f   m 
# 500 500
```

Comment: Dear jay.sf, offered solutions are marvellous. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @mochi Always happy to help! Note my small edit to second solution to make it independent from the first. Please also consider to answer questions as answered, thanks.